# Flask reloader crashes with "no module named Scripts\flask" on Windows

Tags: python, windows, flask, werkzeug

When I run `flask run` on Windows, I get the following error

```
C:\Python37\python.exe: No module named C:\Python37\Scripts\flask
```

This was working previously, the issue started after I created a new env recently.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This was [a bug](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1614) introduced in Werkzeug 0.15.5. Upgrade to at least Werkzeug 0.15.6, which contains the fix. You can also run with `python -m flask run` instead to work around it.