# Flask can't run in development mode, can't find flask module

Tags: python, flask

I'm on Windows, using git bash.
I'm able to run Flask if it's not in development mode. If I set FLASK_ENV to "development" to try to trigger debugging and other helpful things, then `flask run` fails.

The error message is pretty peculiar.

```
$ flask run
 * Serving Flask app "Neuroethics_Behavioral_Task" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
d:\miniconda3\python.exe: No module named D:\miniconda3\Scripts\flask
```

What's weird is that... in the directory D:\miniconda3\Scripts, there is a flask.exe or flask application file.
By typing "where flask", I get returned `D:\miniconda3\Scripts\flask.exe`. So this executable definitely exists in the location that they're trying to look for, but even then Flask can't seem to find it when I try doing flask run.

How do I approach this?

Edit: some more info. This seems to have to do with the fact that I had Flask previously installed in Anaconda, removed it from anaconda using conda uninstall flask, then I had it installed with pip.

`where flask` gives `D:\miniconda3\Scripts\flask.exe`

but `pip show flask` gives `Location: d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages`. The location offered by pip however DOES NOT contain any flask.exe file whatsoever.

Comment: What happens if you just run the python file that contains your flask app, like "python app.py"

Comment: @SamLegesse The python file that contains my  flask app at the moment is `__init__.py`. I have no other python file in the directory for my flask application at the moment because this is supposed to be a really simple web application. Trying `python __init__.py` returns nothing to the terminal

Comment: If it's just a simple flask app, you should be able to add an if main check at the bottom where you then execute app.run(). Similar to the basic app.py example in this tutorial https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-part-1-project-setup/

Comment: Sorry. So yeah editing `__init__.py` to add that if main check (and also setting `app = Flask(__name__))` then running `python  __init__.py`... works with debug mode enabled.

Comment: Great, glad it worked! I'll add that as an official answer then.

Comment: For anyone who's a little curious, this page is relevant: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/server/

Answer (score 0):

The `flask run` command is recommended, but there's currently an issue with Werkzeug on Windows. See [Flask reloader crashes with "no module named Scripts\flask" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57114348/flask-reloader-crashes-with-no-module-named-scripts-flask-on-windows) for the workaround until the bug is fixed.

If you don't want to use that workaround, you can add an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block and call `app.run(debug=True)` directly, running it as `python app.py`. Again, this is not the recommended way to run Flask and there is another workaround to the bug.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: On second thought, we are almost at a solution The server now starts in debug mode. But going to the address 127.0.0.1:5000/ via a browser now just gets a 404 error, "the requested url was not found on the server. I tried adding a host parameter to app.run(), I tried setting it to 127.0.0.1 but that didn't work.

Comment: Hmm, can you update the question with a summarized version of what your flask app looks like? Just the relevant parts, no need to include the details within each app.route